# Making XML according to XML Schema from data taken from SQL VIEW

Tags: sql, xml, schema

Soon i will be doing xml file from my database according to given XML schema in .xsd file. I made it before but on simple tables with elements with no children. Now, schema is not that simple. Element has chilren and they also got it's children. I don't know how i can map data from my database into xml using that xml schema. For simple data it was very easy. I loaded schema and used it during creating xml file and giving fields from database names of tags in .xsd file. What happens when we got complex elements in schema? How can i map field from database into 3rd lvl elements?